# Set different Lighttpd vhost for internal LAN clients - possibly just RegEx required...?

Tags: regex, lighttpd

I want Lighttpd to display a different page for internal clients and the default page for everyone else.

Between [these](http://barrenfrozenwasteland.com/?q=node/24) [two](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-lighttpd-web-server-setting-up-virtual-hosting.html) links, I have an idea of what I want to do but am not sure of the RegEx I would need to restrict clients using a hostname of [http://]192.168.0.? or [http://]192.168.?.? to a different page. I've been using the following code in lighttpd.conf:

```
server.document-root       = "/var/www/sites"

$HTTP["host"] == "RegExHere" {
        server.document-root    = "/var/www/setup"
}
```

...where for 'RegExHere' I have tried a variety of attempts such as:

```
192\.168\.0\.\d{1,3}(\s|$))+
192\.168\.
[192.168.[0-9]+.]
192\.168\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$
```

...and various combinations thereof. I have no idea whether I'm close, but regardless it only shows me the default page.

Can anyone advise where I may be going wrong please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the =~ syntax to match a regex. Change  `$HTTP["host"] == "RegExHere"` to `$HTTP["host"] =~ "RegExHere"` and one of those regexs should work. `^192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$` should do it.

Found this article on it http://blog.evanweaver.com/2006/06/07/regular-expressions-in-lighttpd-host-redirects/

edit: I think you need to use $HTTP["remoteip"] instead of $HTTP["host"] and it looks like you can do it without regexes.

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "10.0.0.0/8" { url.access-deny = ("") }

$HTTP["remoteip"] == "127.0.0.0/8" { url.access-deny = ("") }
```

http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/27

Comment: That's awesome Hersha thank you.

Seems so obvious now, just missed something so simple!

Comment: @drewstiff Hey I updated my answer. I think you are using the wrong $HTTP variable also.

Comment: Although that will work fine too, it was more that I wanted to show the specialist page when accessed by the internal ip of the server, that way if I do want to access the external site I still can by using the actual domain name.

Thanks for the heads-up though, I shall make a note of that for future reference!